# PHP - logic - if else / or die?

Tags: php, if-statement, logic, die

A simple question, I have this following code:

```
if ($this->someSecurityCheck()) {
   // do stuff

} else {
   // show alert message
   redirect(‘index');
}
```

and for better legibility (the code is big), I’m wondering to change it to:

```
if (!$this->someSecurityCheck()) {
   // show alert message
   redirect(‘index');
   die();
}

// do stuff
```

I know that both should work, but the second seems logically „incorrect“. Any thoughts?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with the second code. Why does it feel incorrect to you?

Comment: It’s more a feeling that the code stops where it shouldn’t. If you think in terms of fluxogram, it is an inelegant structure. Feels a bit like the GOTO keyword in Basic.

Comment: It's a perfectly logical structure. If this was placed inside a function, a `return` would be in the place of `die` and I can't think of a better thing than stopping the execution of a script at the point where it's done and anything that follows doesn't matter.

Comment: I see your point, thanks. I’m thinking now, that there are lots of places on my code, where I could use the same structure instead of if/else. In this case there would be lots of „loose dead ends“ in the code. I think that is what is annoying me.

Comment: Logic is the same. The 2nd is bette readable because of less nesting.